# Why my test throws Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click the 'Contact Us' link on this web page. When I use the findelement options using either xpath, cssselector, linktext, I get this error. Some of the solutions suggested the following: I right clicked the page and click View Page Source and searched for *iFrames. However, I could not find any*. So I don't think it is switchto.frame() issue?
I also tried to *remove*'*' from the xpath, but that did not work either.

I also added *Thread.sleep()*, but that also hasn't resolved the issue?

**Selenium Code in Java:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Chromedriver/ChromeDriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://my.voya.com/voyasso/index.html?domain=voyaretirement.voya.com#/login-pweb");

            String window1 = driver.getWindowHandle();
            System.out.println("The Window Handle is " +window1);
        //  driver.switchTo().frame(window1);
            WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"header-info\"]/a"));

            link.click();
            Thread.sleep(8000);
            String window2 = driver.getWindowHandle();
            System.out.println("The Window Handle is " +window2);


        }

    }
```

Here is html code for which I am trying to click Contact Us to open in another Window.:

```
<a class="b au-target" target="_blank" au-target-id="5" href="https://voyaretirement.voya.com/einfo/contactus.aspx?domain=voyaretirement.voya.com&amp;cl=INGWIN&amp;page=prelogin&amp;pl=dummy">Contact Us</a>
```

Here is the error message from the console

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="header-info"]/a"}

Comment: Try to move your `Thread.sleep()` before `driver.findElement()`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I moved it above *driver.findElement()*. However, I continue to get the same error.

Comment: There was an earlier comment about a missing element with id of header-info. That element is very clearly present. I also do not see anything wrong with the xpath. I am able to add a wait before the driver.findElement and I see clicking on Contact Us opening another tab. The challenge here seems to be in the way front-end is getting loaded. Soon after the url is launched, a spinner appears and then the page is loaded. The wait helps by getting past this spinner. A better approach would be to use ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By) with the locator for the spinner.

Comment: I am using Chrome. However when I run the test in Eclipse it just opens the webpage but doesn't click Contact Us for me, even after following above suggestion of moving *Thread.sleep()* before *driver.findElement()*. Also, when I am running the test, I see a spinner but then the page loads within 2 seconds?

Comment: Network latency or the lack of it might be preventing you from seeing it. The visibility of the spinner is much more pronounced in Firefox. Here is the part of the DOM that is changing after page load ...<div class="voya-indicator__inner-container">
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-fw"></i>
            <div class="voya-indicator__message"></div>
        </div>... this is greyed out after page load and is representing the spinner

Comment: Yes I saw it now but is only for a couple of seconds ! (In Chrome)

Comment: Ok, but does this code that I pasted above work for you? Is it opening the Contact Us in a new tab? So, do you think this is a network issue for me and is there a way to get past it? I am not familiar with the above code that you mentioned about Expected Conditions

Comment: Not a n/w issue. This is pretty standard behavior with modern Angular front-ends. I was able to run the snippet from you, move the sleep before defining link WebElement and open the Contact Us in a new tab, consistently. Thread.sleep isn't a great option and code or network change will easily break the test. More advisable approach is [Explicit and Implicit Waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits).

Comment: Thank you ! Tried out the above suggestion and it works ! Appreciated.

Comment: A front-end developer on the project should be able to tell you the xpath or id for the spinner. I would for it to become invisible, add some more explicit waits for other elements on the page to ensure the greatest likelihood that the page has loaded and now is a good time to click on Contact Us.

Comment: Got it ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to add a wait for the element to be clickable then click it.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='header-info']/a"))).click();
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. If this, or any other answer, was useful, upvote it. If this answered your question, please accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have shared a better xpath to use would be:

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'contactus')]"));
```

This will return the first element that has a href with the word contactus in it.

Since you have not provided the full html of the page, it is very difficult to tell whether this element exists in the default frame or not, but if it does exist in a separate frame then you will need to switch to that frame before you attempt to find the element.

Comment: <div id="header">
  <div id="logo" title="Company Logo">
   <img id="logo-img" src.bind="logoPath" class="au-target" au-target-id="3" src="https://voyaretirement.voya.com/static/ingwin/images/logo.png">
  </div><!--anchor-->
  <div id="header-features">
   <div id="header-info"><a class="b au-target" target="_blank" au-target-id="5" href="https://voyaretirement.voya.com/einfo/contactus.aspx?domain=voyaretirement.voya.com&amp;cl=INGWIN&amp;page=prelogin&amp;pl=dummy">Contact Us</a><!--anchor--></div><!--anchor-->
   <div id="header-title">Your Retirement Plan</div>
  </div>
 </div>

Comment: I went to Inspect and then identified the element using 'Select an Element to Inspect it' button and then right clicked on the highlighted part to get the xpath and this what it copied in Chrome